# Python Code containing OpenCV is not detecting object in my image

Tags: python, opencv

I am very new to OpenCV and Python. So, for my first project to recognize objects, I am using a small test file in python. This is the test file

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Opening image
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

# OpenCV opens images as BRG
# but we want it as RGB We'll
# also need a grayscale version
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


# Use minSize because for not
# bothering with extra-small
# dots that would look like STOP signs
stop_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')

found = stop_data.detectMultiScale(img_gray,
                                   minSize=(20,20))
amount_found = len(found)

if amount_found != 0:

    # There may be more than one
    # sign in the image
    for (x, y, width, height) in found:

        # We draw a green rectangle around
        # every recognized sign
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y),
                      (x + height, y + width),
                      (0, 255, 0), 5)

# Creates the environment of
# the picture and shows it
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.show()
```

The tutorial that I saw told me to use a premade `cascade.xml` file. However, I wanted to train my cascade file to recognize a simple apple logo, which I cropped from a photo. I copy pasted the same image multiple times into one folder titled `p`. For the negative images, I used a folder titled `n`. After this, I used the GUI cascade trainer and trained a cascade file. However, when I use the same image (uncropped) in the python program, there is no output.

This is the image which I used to train:

[image: Image which I used to train]

This is the original image which I put in the python script

[image]

The original image is of size 422*612 and the cropped image is of size 285*354. I had set the size in the trainer to `height=20` and `width=15`.

These are my settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Folder `p`:
[image]

Output of program:
[image]
Cascade GUI log end

```
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    0 : 0
Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong ? Please ask if I have to provide anymore information. Is there any ratio relation between the positive image and the actual image that I am missing on ?

UPDATE: I added some more negative images and am now getting this output:
[image]

Comment: Did you use 0 negative samples?

Comment: No, @Micka, I used around 850 negative image samples

Comment: Your acceptance ratio says that no suitable negative samples was found.

Comment: So, should I add more negative images ?

Comment: You should use diverse positive and negative data. You must use negative data where false positives will be found, so that the training can search features to discriminate between positive and negative

Comment: If your posted NEG count is in the first stage it looks more like that your negative samples weren't found by the training at all.

Comment: Can you post the full log?

Comment: @Micka, I had initially tried to post the full log, but its exceeding the total count

Comment: In your cropped postive sample, is the aspect ratio unchanged and 15:20?

Comment: The aspect ratio is 285*384

Comment: Since you are presenting extremely similar positive samples the training might be overfitting to too specific features which are a bit different when resizing the image to a different aspect ratio (or using different interpolation in training and detection). You could try to crop exactly 15*N x 20xN from the original image or to present completely difrerent input samples. There's also a createsamplea app which allows you to augment and generate additional samples.

Comment: @Micka, I tried exactly what you said. I first cropped the training image to a ratio of 15:20. Then, I trained the classifier using this image. After this, I tried to use the same image (having the same ratio) as the input to the program. Still, I got no luck.